# Creating an array of timestamps removing hours between an start and end period

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I'm currently working on an app where people can schedule services from registered professionals. The idea is simple, a user will open the app, select the professional and an agenda will be shown with all available hours.

The professional has an starting and end working hours for a day and the service has a duration, so he may have lots of services to a single day.

What i'm doing currently after selecting a professional and the service (i'll be posting related code below):

- I get the working hours of a professional, from sunday to saturday what days does he works and the time he starts and finishes working.
- I get his agenda, what he already has scheduled, the services starting and finishing hours.
- I create an array where the first entry is the professional starting hour, them i sum the duration of the service and keep doing this until it reaches the finishing hour.
- Then i make a loop to remove any available hour that may have an service scheduled.

Here's an example of the variables i work with:

```js
weekDay = {
  startHour: '08:00AM', endHour: '05:00PM'
};
serviceDuration = 30;
agenda = [
  {"from": 1572683400000, "to": 1572685200000}, 
  {"from": 1572685200000, "to": 1572687000000},
  {"from": 1572688800000, "to": 1572690600000}, 
  {"from": 1572694200000, "to": 1572696000000},
  {"from": 1572696000000, "to": 1572699600000}, 
  {"from": 1572705000000, "to": 1572706800000},
  {"from": 1572711300000, "to": 1572713100000}
];
baseArray = ['08:00AM', '08:30AM', '09:00AM', '09:30AM', ..., '04:30PM'];
// The baseArray is also converted to timestamp, this is just to demonstrate
// Agenda is called removeArray in the code
```

For what i'm doing it works perfectly, but something new just came up and we need to generate the available times based on when a service in agenda has ended.

So let's say i have a service with 45 minutes duration, i start working at 08:00 and there's already something booked from 8:30 to 9:00. Adding the duration as i'm doing now it i would have this: `['08:00', '08:45', '09:30']`. But what i need is the next available time to be when the service already booked ends, so it should be something like: `['08:00', '09:00']`;

I've came up with a code where i check if the current hour beeing added is in the middle of a current booked service, if it is i return the service end to be the next value to be compared. Here's the code i have now:

```
  let startHour = new Date(`${currentDay}T${weekDay.startHour}:00.000Z`).getTime();
  const endHourTime = new Date(`${currentDay}T${weekDay.endHour}:00.000Z`).getTime();

  if (startHour <= endHourTime) {
    while (startHour < endHourTime && endHourTime - startHour >= duration) {
      baseArray.push(startHour);
      startHour = getNextAvailableTime(startHour, duration, removeArray);
    }
  }

function getNextAvailableTime(startHour, duration, removeArray) {
  const filterArray = [];
    for (let i = 0, max = removeArray.length; i < max; i++) {
      if ((startHour >= removeArray[i].from && startHour < removeArray[i].to)) {
        filterArray.push(removeArray[i].to);
        break;
      }
    }

    if (filterArray.length > 0) {
      return filterArray[0];
    } else {
      return startHour + duration;
    }
  }
}
```

This is puting me in a infinite loop always geting the end of the first value in the removeArray. Any idea what am i doing wrong? If you need better explaining i'll be happy to do so